# How to know ASP.NET publishings dates over time when using File System method

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that has been published over the time each time a new features and/or some bugs have been implemented/corrected.

The publishing has been made by a external IT consultancy and they have not kept track of the publishings made so now I am trying to know when those publishings were made over the time independently of the method used to publish, WebDeploy, FileSystem, FTP. In my case I know they were made using FileSystem method and from Visual Studio 2013 IDE by making use of publishing Wizard. So is there any way to know each publishing date made over time? Maybe some logs in IIS?

Comment: you can check the published folder path->bin folder->and the date of the .dll file. this shows the last modified date.

Comment: Yes, this shows the last modified date but not all the times this dll has been published over time.

Comment: iis can not this kind of information, it is server-side logging.you can get more detail about iis logging by this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/iis-logging).the only way of is you can check the last modified date of the folder or file. this is the responsibility of the IT consultancy to keep track of the publishing.